# Using Google Maps for Directions and Address Validation via PHP?

Tags: php, api, mapping

This project is fairly simple yet, complicated.

- 50+ addresses are present
- User will input or import addresses
- Script must take addresses and provide non-optimized(or optimized [fastest/shortest]) direction between each address
- Script must be able to map directions on map and provide information such as total distance, proximate time.
- On side note script must validate address if it's valid or not. If not then tell user to fix it.

So far the company was using a desktop application for tracking, routing, directions, etc.

Now they want a web version.

I was thinking about using microsoft's bing service or google's maps.

Which do you think would suit better?

Comment: This will be used for kinda commercial purposes

Comment: Also the addresses will be stored in database. I know address is a private information and sending such to google or just anywhere in internet is no no. But I have been told to do so anyway.

Comment: commercial purposes is fine, it just technically, according to Google's terms, needs to be publicly accessible. Sending addresses as such is okay IMO, as long as you don't send any private information (like names) with it. (I accidentally deleted my first comment)

Comment: An address is only private information if it can be linked to an individual isn't it?.  Gmaps already does directions/routing/estimated time - though this happens in JS and is not available via the API as far as I can can recall - it also has greater familiarity amongst users. Using Gmaps v3 no API key is required, and it is mobile (browser) ready.

Answer (score 1):

For address validation you could use Google's [Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/). It's not a perfect solution as it allows for addresses that might be partially wrong. An example is a user typing in 3002 Such and Such Street when 3002 doesn't actually exist.

Also, if the link doesn't have to be internal then you can provide a link to Google maps with the format http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=[STARTING ADDRESS]&daddr=[DESTINATION ADDRESS]

I'd imagine there is also a way to handle directions with the Maps API but I'm not sure.